# How to set dynamic weight attribute and call another xml files android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i have created a common xml file as common_linear_layout which has basically width, height and dynamic weight attribute.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight='@{weight_size}'></LinearLayout>
```

Then i want to include any xml files with any weight size

```
<include
    layout="@layout/common_linear_layout{'1'}" />
```

is it possible?

Comment: do it by calling `new LinearLayout(...)` and setting its `LayoutParams`

Comment: i want to apply this settings from .xml file.

Comment: use [databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) then